# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dash'

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I need to have the latest version for dash.

But I already have dash.

```
brew info dash
Warning: Treating dash as a formula. For the cask, use homebrew/cask/dash
dash: stable 0.5.11.5 (bottled), HEAD
```

When I try to run my app, I am getting the following:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dash'

I am trying to upgrade dash, but I am getting:

```
dash 0.5.11.5 already installed
```

I want to have the version 2.2.0 but I can not upgrade it. I tried

```
brew install dash@2.2.0
```

but it does not work.

Comment: That ModuleNotFoundError is from Python, so I assume you are running a Python app. That error means you need to install a Python module. But you seem to be installing the wrong module. Don't you mean this "dash" https://dash.plotly.com/? See https://dash.plotly.com/installation

Comment: you probably have multiple versions of python installed and you're not using the one that has dash